# OmegaT team project with Git

Tags: git

Can anyone tell how to set up git-based OmegaT team project?
The official help explains the SVN case, and I guess the way on git might be similar with it, but I cannot get the correct procedure:

For example, let say when I have just "git init" /opt/translation as a git repository of OmegaT project, how should I input into repository url field in the popup window for "Download team project"?
I tried several patterns(/opt/translation, /opt/translation/.git etc.), in vain, saying that it is an invalid repository url.

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard git repository notations such as

- user@host:path/to/project.git
- https://host/path/to/project.git
- file:///local/path/to/project

OmegaT will not recognize the git repository as a valid repository if it is empty. You need to have at least one commit; it can be anything, such as an empty `.gitignore`.

However the team project download will give an error if the resulting checkout does not contain at least a minimal OmegaT project. From the root it must at least have these files:

```
.
├── omegat
│   └── project_save.tmx
└── omegat.project
```

The `git!` prefix is generally not needed; it's only intended to be used as a last resort when autodetection fails, but even then we'd appreciate it if you [reported](https://sourceforge.net/p/omegat/bugs/new/) such cases.

Answer (score 0):

When entering the URL for the "Download team project" window, for git projects, use the following pattern:

git!ssh://user@yourdomain.com/opt/translation.git

The git! is probably what you were missing, the rest of the git URL should look familiar if you have ever checked out a remote git project. Of course, if you are working off of a local IP address rather than a domain, you can replace the yourdomain.com with the IP address.

Comment: It's not a big deal in a post this short but consider formatting commands as code for readability.